# Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number

Tags: apache-spark, java-8

I  have installed Java 8 through the website. Meanwhile, for apache-spark, python, scala were installed using Homebrew. Previously, I have also installed Java 8 through homebrew but then I keep getting error PyJ4.
But now, when I Java was installed separately, the runtime error keep coming up.

I have been reading the solution of this error but most of them keep suggesting to set a JAVA_HOME and Pyspark_home. How do I do that in Mac ? I tried in windows and it was successfully run without error but what do I need to do in Mac ?

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Test Spark').getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext

```
/Users/ainaazazi/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /Users/ainaazazi/opt/anaconda3/bin/java: No such file or directory
/Users/ainaazazi/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/bin/spark-class: line 96: CMD: bad array subscript
head: illegal line count -- -1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/01/g4x6z44s45q86gcnbs0czn9w0000gn/T/ipykernel_4609/3137907738.py in <module>
      1 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
      2 
----> 3 spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Test Spark').getOrCreate()
      4 
      5 sc = spark.sparkContext

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py in getOrCreate(self)
    226                             sparkConf.set(key, value)
    227                         # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
--> 228                         sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    229                     # Do not update `SparkConf` for existing `SparkContext`, as it's shared
    230                     # by all sessions.

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    390         with SparkContext._lock:
    391             if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 392                 SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    393             return SparkContext._active_spark_context
    394 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    142                 " is not allowed as it is a security risk.")
    143 
--> 144         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    145         try:
    146             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/context.py in _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    337         with SparkContext._lock:
    338             if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 339                 SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
    340                 SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    341 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py in launch_gateway(conf, popen_kwargs)
    106 
    107             if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
--> 108                 raise RuntimeError("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
    109 
    110             with open(conn_info_file, "rb") as info:

RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

Installed apache-spark through Homebrew and Java 8 through website

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have set `JAVA_HOME=/Users/ainaazazi/opt/anaconda3/bin/java`, which is not correct.

The method you use to install Java shouldn't matter. For example, I use `sdkman` and others use `asdf-java`. But your real error is on the first line of what you've posted, not the last line.

Spark supports Java 11; 8 is end of life. So upgrade, then debug your installation by running `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version` directly, first, which is what Spark needs.

> How do I do that in Mac ?

It's an environment variable, so search how you can set those. For example, edit your bash/zshrc file.

You can also edit the spark-env.sh file to fix Spark itself (assuming you've installed it with homebrew or downloaded directly, not used pip/conda).